# How to write the form to get search result from yahoo finance?

Tags: html, forms, get

The form can output google'search for inputed text.

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
<p class="nav">
<input size="-1" value="Search" type="submit"><br>
<input name="q" size="16" maxlength="255" type="text"> 
<input name="sitesearch" value="www.example.com" type="hidden">
</p>
</form>
```

To open it with firefox and input `robot` .

[image]

To click search button ,we get the googl's search result.

[image]

One  question here:can google search engine receive and handle the parameters in `<input name="sitesearch" value="www.example.com" type="hidden">`?

Now i want to get yahoo finace search result with the same form,rewrite it as

```
<form method="get" action="http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/">
<p class="nav">
<input size="-1" value="Search" type="submit"><br>
<input name="q" size="16" maxlength="255" type="text"> 
</p>
</form>
```

I can't get anythin when to input `fnma` and to click search buttom.

[image]
[image]

How to rewrite the action to get the below serch result with yahoo finance?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo Finance search doesn't appear to work in the same way as google search does.

With Google as you mentioned you just send a GET variable of q=$searchterm and it will show the results, however yahoo finance's search engine appears to be done on page using AJAX, meaning you can't link to it. When you type a query it searches without going to a separate page and presents the result as a search suggestion.

Unless they have an API available to use for searching then I would imagine this isn't possible just by using a html form.

Comment: One more  question here:can google search engine receive and handle the parameters in <input name="sitesearch" value="www.example.com" type="hidden">?

Comment: As far as I know, that isn't built in. One way of doing it is to amend site:finance.yahoo.com+$searchterm to the input. Maybe a jQuery solution would be the best way of doing this:

Comment: `<script>
$("#myinput").change(function(){
$(this).val("site:finance.yahoo.com+"+$(this).val());
});
</script>